# Значение не приводится к числу

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE `officers`
(
    ...
    `isOnline` TINYINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0,
    ...
);
```

При авторизации отправляю такой запрос:

```
UPDATE officers SET isOnline = 1 WHERE id = ${ id };
```

При выходе соответственно

```
UPDATE officers SET isOnline = 0 WHERE id = ${ id };
```

Однако когда я получаю данные из таблицы, то для разлогиненых пользователей isOnline получаю 0 (число), а вот для залогиненых " " (пустая строка).

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: не показываете весь код, а именно ту его часть в которой проблемма.

Comment: @Владимир Клыков, ну собственно, да. Я не описывал окружение, т.к. считал его непринципиальным. А дело оказалось в нем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, оказывается дело в поведении node.js, который переводит ответ из бд с типом данных BIT в свой тип данных, некий Buffer (столкнулся впервые).

При выводе в консоль значения rows[0].isOnline на экране отображается `<Buffer 00>` или `<Buffer 01>`. Я беру isOnline[0] и получаю нормальное число.